# Android CameraX VideoRecorder error > Encoder cannot created : null

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-jetpack, android-camerax

I am building an Android app that records video using Camera X.
The probe in a Samsung A52 and it works correctly.
When running on a Galaxy Core A03 I get these errors:

> E/Recorder: Unable to initialize video encoder.
> androidx.camera.video.internal.encoder.InvalidConfigException: Encoder cannot created: null
> at androidx.camera.video.internal.workaround.EncoderFinder.findEncoder(EncoderFinder.java:88)
> at androidx.camera.video.internal.encoder.EncoderImpl.(EncoderImpl.java:214)
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder.setupVideo(Recorder.java:1294)
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder.initializeInternal(Recorder.java:998)
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder.lambda$onSurfaceRequested$0$androidx-camera-video-Recorder(Recorder.java:396)
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder$$ExternalSyntheticLambda16.run(Unknown Source:4)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$1.run(SequentialExecutor.java:111)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:231)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java:173)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7815)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:593)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1094)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
> at android.media.MediaCodec.(MediaCodec.java:1912)
> at android.media.MediaCodec.createByCodecName(MediaCodec.java:1890)
> at androidx.camera.video.internal.workaround.EncoderFinder.findEncoder(EncoderFinder.java:85)
> at androidx.camera.video.internal.encoder.EncoderImpl.(EncoderImpl.java:214) 
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder.setupVideo(Recorder.java:1294) 
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder.initializeInternal(Recorder.java:998) 
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder.lambda$onSurfaceRequested$0$androidx-camera-video-Recorder(Recorder.java:396) 
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder$$ExternalSyntheticLambda16.run(Unknown Source:4) 
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$1.run(SequentialExecutor.java:111) 
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:231) 
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java:173) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7815) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:593) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1094) 
> D/Recorder: Transitioning Recorder internal state: INITIALIZING --> ERROR
> D/PreviewView: Surface requested by Preview.
> D/SurfaceViewImpl: Surface created.
> D/SurfaceViewImpl: Surface changed. Size: 960x720
> D/PreviewView: Preview transformation info updated. TransformationInfo{cropRect=Rect(0, 0 - 960, 720), rotationDegrees=90, targetRotation=0}
> D/PreviewTransform: Transformation info set: TransformationInfo{cropRect=Rect(0, 0 - 960, 720), rotationDegrees=90, targetRotation=0} 960x720 false
> D/SurfaceViewImpl: Surface set on Preview.
> D/SyncCaptureSessionBase: [androidx.camera.camera2.internal.SynchronizedCaptureSessionBaseImpl@d97cfb7] getSurface...done
> D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@1dd1e08[id=0]} Posting surface closed
> java.lang.Throwable
> at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.postSurfaceClosedError(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1174)
> at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$2.onFailure(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1116)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.futures.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:340)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:231)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java:173)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
> D/DeferrableSurface: surface closed,  useCount=0 closed=true androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@3051f61
> D/DeferrableSurface: Surface terminated[total_surfaces=2, used_surfaces=0](androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@3051f61}
> D/DeferrableSurface: Surface created[total_surfaces=3, used_surfaces=0](androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@8dfc68e}
> D/Recorder: Surface is requested in state: ERROR, Current surface: 0
> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.mrkevin574.teteo, PID: 16045
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Surface was requested when the Recorder had encountered error androidx.camera.video.internal.ResourceCreationException: androidx.camera.video.internal.encoder.InvalidConfigException: Encoder cannot created: null
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder.onSurfaceRequested(Recorder.java:406)
> at androidx.camera.video.VideoCapture.createPipeline(VideoCapture.java:416)
> at androidx.camera.video.VideoCapture.resetPipeline(VideoCapture.java:482)
> at androidx.camera.video.VideoCapture.lambda$createPipeline$0$androidx-camera-video-VideoCapture(VideoCapture.java:433)
> at androidx.camera.video.VideoCapture$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onError(Unknown Source:10)
> at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.lambda$postSurfaceClosedError$14(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1175)
> at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda7.run(Unknown Source:4)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7815)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:593)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1094)
> V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 3688
> D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=HIGHEST, name=FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_REPORT for destination cct
> D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Scheduling upload for context TransportContext(cct, HIGHEST, MSRodHRwczovL2NyYXNobHl0aWNzcmVwb3J0cy1wYS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MS9maXJlbG9nL2xlZ2FjeS9iYXRjaGxvZ1xBSXphU3lCcnBTWVQ0RkZMMDlyZUhKaTZIOUZZZGVpU25VVE92Mk0=) with jobId=-1451806366 in 1000ms(Backend next call timestamp 1649111614302). Attempt 1
> I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16045 SIG: 9

here the code of getVideoCapture():

```
    private fun getVideoCapture() : VideoCapture<Recorder>{

    val qualitySelector = QualitySelector.fromOrderedList(
        listOf(Quality.UHD, Quality.FHD, Quality.HD, Quality.SD),
        FallbackStrategy.lowerQualityOrHigherThan(Quality.SD)
    )


    val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
        .setExecutor(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))
        .setQualitySelector(qualitySelector)
        .build()

    
    return VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)
}
```

I have it exactly as the Android documentation tells me.

Comment: Be aware that the [Galaxy Core A03](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_a03_core-11215.php) is a low end Android Go device with 2 GB of RAM.

Comment: do you know any other alternative?

Comment: This error log state that there is a ResourceCreationException. An exception is thrown to indicate an error has occurred while creating necessary resources. So the problem is in the device. Try to debug and find out the exact issues and post. I hope we can be of help.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I`m also facing the same issue on camera 1.1.0-beta01 version

Answer (score 1):

I'm also having the same error after learning about CameraX at the following link https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started

I think it's true what [Morrison Chang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295004/morrison-chang) said, there is something problem with Low End Android devices.

So I downgraded the quality of the Recorder contained inside the startCamera() function from HIGHEST to SD or HD and it's work.

```
 val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
     //.setQualitySelector(QualitySelector.from(Quality.HIGHEST))
     .setQualitySelector(QualitySelector.from(Quality.SD))//change to Quality.SD or Quality.HD
     .build()
 videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)
```